# Drop the lowest grade java program

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I am writing a java program that will read from keyboard 4 inputs, named Test1, Test2, Test3, Final. The program will then determine the best 2 (BTest1, BTest2) out of the 3 test grades of Test 1, 2, and 3. Then, it will compute the final grade using the following grading policy:
BTest1: 30%  BTest2: 30%  Final: 40%

Here is what I got:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);


        int Test1 = 0,
                Test2 = 0,
                Test3 = 0,
                Final = 0;


        double AVG;

        // Test 1 input
        System.out.println ("Enter Test 1: ");
        Test1 = scan.nextInt();

        while ((Test1 < 0) || (Test1 > 100))
        {
            System.out.println ("Invalid Input, try again.");
            Test1 = scan.nextInt();

        }

        // Test 2 input
        System.out.println ("Enter Test 2: ");
        Test2 = scan.nextInt();

        while ((Test2 < 0) || (Test2 > 100))
        {
            System.out.println ("Invalid Input, try again.");
            Test2 = scan.nextInt();

        }

        // Test 3 input
        System.out.println ("Enter Test 3: ");
        Test3 = scan.nextInt();

        while ((Test3 < 0) || (Test3 > 100))
        {
            System.out.println ("Invalid Input, try again.");
            Test3 = scan.nextInt();

        }

        // Final Exam input
        System.out.println ("Enter Final Exam: ");
        Final = scan.nextInt();

        while ((Final < 0) || (Final > 100))
        {
            System.out.println ("Invalid Input, try again.");
            Final = scan.nextInt();

        }


        // Find the highest out of the 3 tests
        int BTest1,
            BTest2;

        if ((Test1 >= Test2) && (Test1 >= Test3))
             BTest1 = Test1;
        if ((Test2 >= Test1) && (Test2 >=Test3))
            BTest2 = Test2;
        if ((Test3 >= Test1) && (Test3 >= Test2)) 
            BTest2 = Test3;


        // Compute the Average
        AVG = ((BTest1 * .3) + (BTest2 * .3) + (Final * .4));

                if (AVG >= 90)
                    System.out.println ("A " + AVG); 
                else
                    if (AVG >= 80)
                        System.out.println ("B " + AVG);
                    else
                        if (AVG >= 70)
                            System.out.println ("C " + AVG);
                        else
                            if (AVG >= 60)
                                System.out.println ("D " + AVG);
                            else
                                System.out.println ("F " + AVG);



    }
}
```

The problem that I am encountering is that I am not able to drop the lowest grade.
Can someone please guid me in the right direction please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you assume that Test1 will automatically be either higher than Test2 or Test3, but if it is not (e.g. 10, 50, 60), BTest1 will never be set. To do this properly, you need a very long series of if/else calls. But there is a simpler way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  final int[] testScores = new int[3]; // use an array here
  Arrays.fill(testScores, -1); // set all to -1 to know if we already got a proper input

  for (int i = 0; i < testScores.length; ++i) { // for loop simplifies the whole thing a lot
    while ((testScores[i] < 0) || (testScores[i] > 100)) {
      System.out.println("Please enter Test " + (i + 1) + ":");
      testScores[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
  }   

  int exam = -1; // Final is a bad name, because final is a reserved word
  while ((exam < 0) || (exam > 100)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter Final Exam:");
    exam = scan.nextInt();
  }

  Arrays.sort(testScores); // automatically sorts the entry from lowest to highest
  final double AVG = (testScores[testScores.length - 1] + testScores[testScores.length - 2]) * 0.3 + exam * 0.4; // therefore the best grades are the last two entries

  if (AVG >= 90) {
    System.out.println("A " + AVG);
  } else if (AVG >= 80) {
    System.out.println("B " + AVG);
  } else if (AVG >= 70) {
    System.out.println("C " + AVG);
  } else if (AVG >= 60) {
    System.out.println("D " + AVG);
  } else {
    System.out.println("F " + AVG);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
TreeSet<Integer> tests = new TreeSet<Integer>();
tests.add(test1);
tests.add(test2);
tests.add(test3);

if (tests.size() == 1) {
    bTest1 = tests.last();
    bTest2 = tests.poolLast();
} else {
    bTest1 = tests.poolLast();
    bTest2 = tests.poolLast();
}
```

It will make a set of at most 3 elements, and then retrieve 2 biggest elements of the set (also handle situation when there is only 1 element in set - all inserted values were the same).

Take a look at [Java naming conventions](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html). All your variables look like classes to me.

EDIT: Changed places of `bTest1` and `bTest2` - not that it would change anything (see comment).

Comment: Besides that the function is named `pollLast` your code will fetch the best grade into bTest2 (which is the second best) and the 2nd best into bTest1. Your check for only 1 element will in addition produce fake grades which do not exist.

Comment: As I see it it is required to enter 3 values with 3 tests results, and those values are put into `tests` set explicitly. `tests.size() == 1` ONLY in case `test1 == test2 == test3`. So it would NOT produce any fake grade.

Thing with which bTest is *first* and which is *last* can be easily repaired - not that it would change anything since in final grade calculation is not assumed any order of those.